# How to install ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I seem to have lost all my ASP.NET MVC 5 templates when creating a new project, and when I try to add a view to an existing MCV 5 site, this option, which used to be there:

> "MVC 5 View Page with (Layout Razor)."

Is no longer there.
 I went to https://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5 and it says to download Visual Studio 2015 community edition , or MVC 5 support for VS 2013. I am using VS 2015 Profession with update 2. I uninstalled update 3 thinking that's what did it.
 Thanks,

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click the 'New Item...' option?

Comment: @DCruz22 I reinstalled update 3, and it is working again. Thanks,.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling update 3 seems to have fixed the issue.